# Thousands separator with Input mask

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm going to use [**this mask**](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) with Ionic 3 app. I have setup the project for this.

*.ts*

```
 this.masks = {
      budget: ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/],
    }
```

*.html*

```
   <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="project.budget" [textMask]="{mask: 
 masks.budget}"></ion-input>
```

**Q:** Above mask is just a phone number one.Can you tell me how to do thousand separated input mask here?

Hope I can use below `reg ex-pattern`.But how can I apply it to a `masks` array?

```
^\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*$
```

`budget` values are `numeric`.No decimals.e.g. `100,000`, `25,000` like that.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily do this task by using [**createNumberMask**](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons#createnumbermask) addon.

*.ts*

```
  const numberMask = createNumberMask({
      prefix: '',
      thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ','
    })
    this.masks = {
      budget: numberMask,
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It is super awesome.But you must select a `right version` with `Ionic`. Please see this: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/617#issuecomment-322292363 @sebaferreras